# In a finite measure space, uniform integrability implies $L^p$ bounded?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

In the probability ambient we work with a measure space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ that is of finite measure (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)<+\infty$).

I'm interest to understad all the relation between uniform integrable and $L^p$-bounded family.

Just for completeness i remember the main definitions:

**UI**:A family $(X_i)_{i \in \mathscr{I}}$ is called UI if

$ \sup_{i\in \mathscr{I}}\mathbb{E}(|X_i|\chi(|X_i|\geq K)) \to 0$ as $K\to+\infty$

$\mathbf{L^p}$**-bounded** :A family $(X_i)_{i \in \mathscr{I}}$ is called $L^p$-bounded if

$$\sup_{i\in \mathscr{I}}\mathbb{E}(|X_i|^p) < +\infty$$

So i know that:

1. UI implies $L^1$-bounded
2. $L^1$-bounded not implies UI
3. $L^p$-bounded implies UI when p>1
   My question is: Is true the inverse implication of 3. ?

Comment: No. Take a function $f$ that is in $L_1\setminus L_2$ , for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ in $[0,1]$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. The family $\{f\}$ is UI but not $L_2$ anything.

Comment: More generally, consider $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x(|\ln x|+1)^2}.$$
Then $f \in L^1(0,1),$ but $f \notin L^p(0,1)$ for all $p>1.$ Then $\{f\}$ is UI but not $L_p$ anything for all al $p>1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, if $\mathscr{F}$ is uniformly integrable there may not exist a $p>1$ for which $\mathscr{F}$ is $L^p$ bounded. For example, if for all functions $f\in\mathscr{F}$ we have

$$\int_\Omega |f|\ln(1+|f|) \leq C $$

Then the family $\mathscr{F}$ is uniformly integrable.

In general, if
$G:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is increasing and grows superlinearly and we have $\int_\Omega G(|f|) \leq C$ for all $f\in\mathscr{F}$, then $\mathscr{F}$ is uniformly integrable, and the converse is also true: uniform integrability implies the existence of such a $G$. For a proof, see Bogachev Measure Theory, Theorem 4.5.9.